# Join with no common Serial_Num column

Tags: oracle, join, subquery, multiple-columns

I am trying to see how I can get these 2 Tables to join they do not have any common columns. Serial_Num is in Aircraft_type TABLE
and Type_, Description_, Capacity_, Range_; are on Acraft_Data TABLE.
The picture is the outputs separately, but trying to get the serial number with the acraft_data.

[image]

> Expected output
> [image]

Comment: Please share the expected output too. Which row of first table needs to be displayed with which row of second table?

Comment: Edited it just now, its uploaded. @Popeye

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join them without any common column then there must be joining based on some row number.

I am assumimg that you need every data from `aircraft_type` table and `aircraft_type` has more records than `aircraft` table then you can use the following query:

```
Select * from
(Select at.*,
        Row_number() over (order by serial_num) as rn
From aircraft_type) at
Join 
(Select a.*,
        Row_number() over (order by capicity) - 1 as rn,
        Count() over () as cnt
From aircraft) a
On mod(at.rn - 1, a.cnt) = a.rn
```